# Setting the map by Divin size?

Tags: python, html, flask-sqlalchemy

I can't change the size of the code at https://codepen.io/sinanelms/pen/MqdNNY. Would you like to help the map grow and shrink according to the size of the screen?

I worked on the following but could not do what I wanted.

```
<style type="text/css">
   body{
   background:#fff;}
   #map{
   width:1050px;
   height:620px;
   position:relative;}
   #map svg {
   position: relative;top:
   -100px; 
   left: 0px;}
   svg > a {cursor: pointer;display:block;}
   #sehir{font-size:30px;text-align:center;margin-top:25px;color:#666;}
</style>
<div>
</div>
<div id="sehir"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Jquery window resize to set `width` and `height` with `setViewBox` and `setSize`. have a look into below code with **window resize**.

**JS**

```
var w = 1000, h=500;
var r = Raphael('map', w, h),
attributes = {
    fill: '#666',
    stroke: '#fff',
    'stroke-width':.5,
    'stroke-linejoin': 'round',
},

arr = new Array();

r.setViewBox(10, 100, w,h,true);
r.setSize('100%', '100%');

$(window).resize(function(){
    r.setViewBox(10,100,w,h,true);
    r.setSize('100%', '100%');
});
```

**CSS**

```
#map {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#map svg {
  position: relative;
}

svg>a {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: I can’t speak English :) I'm translating with Google Translate, sorry for the ridiculous translations  :) @ShivKumarBaghel

Comment: I have a little question, according to a random ID I want to paint that place, I failed to do the following.the code is here. https://codepen.io/sinanelms/pen/MqdNNY?editors=1010                                                                                               
   `//random selected
    function random(){
      
    var ran=Math.floor(Math.random() * 82);
      
    if(obj.id==ran){obj.animate({fill: '#000'}, 200); } 
     }
       
     setInterval(function(){random();}, 1000);
    //random end`

Answer (score 0):

while you initiate `Raphael` with id `map` pass **width** `in %`. 
Below its initiated with `width 100%` and `height 800px`.

`var r = Raphael('map', '100%', '800'),`

also remove `width` & `height` from inline css with `#map`

```
#map{
   width:1050px;
   height:620px;
   position:relative;
}
```

Comment: I have updated `r = Raphael ('map', '100%', '800')` . I removed the width and height from inline css with #map, but it still didn't happen as I wanted.
I want the map to shrink when I reduce the window.var r = Raphael ('map', '100%', '800') When the 800 is 300, half of the map is visible.